# Getting Resolve error while importing project in android studio, Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'

Tags: android, groovy, android-studio, gradle

I am not able to import a project in AndroidStudio because of following error:

```
Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'.
```

I have no idea about the project. Why I am getting this error and how do I fix it.

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I have had a same problem. And I have found a solution.

**Cause**

This problem is caused by **android gradle plugin does not match for gradle version**.

**Solution**

Edit build.gradle in project. gradle plugin version must be satisfied requirements for android studio.

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

And edit distrubutionUrl in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. version of gradle must be satisfied requirements for gradle plugin.

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

You can find version compatibilities between android studio, android gradle plugin and gradle in [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

Answer (score 10):

Apparently 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling' does not work with the new version of Gradle.

Change your project settings so that your project points to an older version of Gradle, like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

EDIT:

As noted in a comment, you can also do:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

Or even reference other versions.

Comment: This 1.1.0 gave me exactly the same error. Changing to **com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0** fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I updated my Android Studio to 1.3 and same error I got. I just removed caches and wrapper from /.gradle/ directory. and It worked.

Answer (score 5):

Edit build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

And edit gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I had set Gradle 1.12 in "Settings..>Gradle" as local gradle distribution, however the project was created by a team mate using gradle 2.2.1

I downloaded gradle 2.2.1 manually and set it as local distribution and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Java sdk support in android studio from `20.0.1` to `17.0.6` and it fixed all my issues.