# Android Studio Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'

Tags: android, groovy, android-studio, gradle, resolve

I installed Android Studio and when I try to import a project from gradle this *resolve error* shows up:

> Unable to load class
>   'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'.

I deleted the files in my Users .gradle folder and tried different gradle versions. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923716/getting-resolve-error-while-importing-project-in-android-studio-unable-to-load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/groovy-2-3-5-out-with-upward-compatibility) page might help solve the problem. What they say is:

> So we leveraged this version to add a new artifact, named
>   groovy-backports-compat23. This artifact shouldn’t be necessary for
>   most of you, but if you face an error like:
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
> ```
>
> in your project, then it means that a class has been compiled with
>   Groovy 2.3+ but that you are trying to use it with an older version of
>   Groovy. By adding this jar on classpath, you give a chance to your
>   program to run. This may be particularily interesting for Gradle users
>   that want to use a plugin built on Gradle 2+ on older versions of
>   Gradle and face this error. Adding the following line to their build
>   files should help:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>     // ...
>     dependencies {
>          classpath 'some plugin build on gradle 2'
>          classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
>     } }
> ```
>
> Note that for now, this jar only contains the ShortTypeHandlingClass.
>   Future versions may include more.
>   - See more at: http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/groovy-2-3-5-out-with-upward-compatibility#sthash.mv7Y8XQv.dpuf

Answer (score 4):

I can fix this error message using these three methods.

1. use latest gradle version
2. use latest android SDK and tools.
3. use proguard-rules.pro

build.gradle (Project:xxxxx)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I ran gradle from command line and that did work.
After that, I found File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle. There "Use local gradle distribution" was active. Changed it to "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I upgraded to Studio 1.3.1 and was dead in the water for a couple of hours until I found your answer!!!!!!!

Comment: You saved my life! After upgrading to Studio 1.5.1 from 1.4.1, I encountered this problem. And this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a same problem. And I have found a solution.

Cause

This problem is caused by android gradle plugin does not match for gradle version.

Solution

Edit build.gradle in project. gradle plugin version must be satisfied requirements for android studio.

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

And edit distrubutionUrl in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. version of gradle must be satisfied requirements for gradle plugin.

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

You can find version compatibilities between android studio, android gradle plugin and gradle in this page

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29695756/3675925